# Does the "running technique" of Seiho players exist in real life?

Tags: kuroko-no-basket

In Episode 7, when they play against Seiho, it shows that the way the Seiho players run is different from the common way (specifically, the way they swing their arms).

Does this running technique exist in real life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this running technique, but I can tell you how important it is to swing your arms properly while running.

Have a Look here ->
[LiveScience Arm Swinging](http://www.livescience.com/46844-natural-arm-swing-saves-runners-energy.html).

> The scientists found that swinging the arms reduced energy costs by 3 percent compared with holding the hands behind the back, 9 percent compared with holding the arms across the chest, and 13 percent compared with holding the hands on top of the head.

If you have a look at professional runners, you will recognize how focused they move their arms. I can't tell if this special arm swinging is working, but there are surely different techniques to reduce your energy cost by swinging your arms.

Comment: The "Old technique" shown in Episode 7 says that they swing their arms slightly. Scientists made the research based on holding arms behind the back.
Maybe the 'old technique' it consumes less energy, but for aerodynamic principles and to get more speed AND spend less energy (professional runners' case) it must be better to swing arms in the common way.

Answer (score 0):

I think that although there are definitely ways of running that minimize energy usage, a basketball team would most likely not implement these, especially on e at the high school level. This is because almost everything in basketball, from the way you dribble, to how you step into your shot, is influenced by the way you run, so the players would essentially have to re-learn how to play the game.